# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error in Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I am trying to use the MATLAB engine through C++ on Xcode 9.4.1 but I am getting an error: "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error". I searched for the answer and found out that turning off the "Bitcode" might help. However, when I go to the Build Setting of Xcode, it is just not there. I highlight, that it is definitely not there, even if you search in the search bar. How can I turn it off, and if I can't, what can I do?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_engEvalString", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"_engOpen", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"_engPutVariable", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"_mxCreateDoubleMatrix_800", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"_mxGetPr_800", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "engine.h"
#define  BUFSIZE 256

int main() {
    Engine *ep ;
    mxArray *Y = NULL, *result = NULL ;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    double x[10] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0,
        8.0, 9.0};
    if (!(ep = engOpen("\0"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    Y = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,10, mxREAL);
    memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(Y), (void *)x, sizeof(x));
    engPutVariable (ep, "Y", Y) ;
    engEvalString(ep, "fx = Y.^2") ;
    engEvalString(ep, "plot(Y,fx);");
    engEvalString(ep, "f(x) = y^2") ;
    engEvalString(ep, "xlabel('x');");
    engEvalString(ep, "ylabel('y');");

    printf("Hit return to continue\n\n");
    fgetc(stdin);
    return 0 ;
}
```

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEqpY.png)

Comment: Are you linking in the MATLAB libraries? Please include your linker command.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Since I am not really sure, which part of my code is a linker, I have included the whole code in the question d.

Comment: Thanks for including the code. That's important too. But I was asking for the linker command. Your code gets compiled by a compiler, then the resulting object code is linked (with libraries) into an executable. This second step is performed by the linker. This linker needs to know which libraries  you use, so it can link them into your executable.

Comment: Your error message is "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error" -- it is saying that the linker (the second step) found an error.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am so sorry but this is way too deep for my knowledge of what is behind the code. Maybe the image that I included in the end of the question as "the error message" link would help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message and the link command shown in the screen grab, it is not linking to the MATLAB libraries. I don't know how to properly set up Xcode to do so.

The best you can do is follow the advice in the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/build-mac-os-x-engine-application.html), which suggests using the `mex` command in MATLAB as follows:

```
mex -v -client engine <filename.cpp>
```

Replace `<filename.cpp>` with the actual source file name, of course. First change directory to the location of that source file, and the executable will be placed next to it.